# How to cook liver in microwave?

Tags: microwave, liver

Delicate parts such as liver, kidney and heart can be quickly fried in a little oil. I wonder if there any way to cook them in the microwave while preserving the tender texture?

Comment: I would be more concerned if it would explode.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried this myself, but I have a suggestion. You could slice the liver as you might when frying it. Then put butter/oil and a single layer of the meat in a glass pan. Cover with a paper towel. Microwave only a few seconds at a time and always keep an eye on it. It could explode or burn. Rotate the meat a few times.
You could also try boiling it, but I'm not sure that's what you want.
I fear the meat will never be as tender as you would with other cooking methods :(
But try it, it'll still be edible, unless you burn it